# How fix to SMS Retriever API

Tags: javascript, android, api, android-studio

I wrote code for example "SMS Retreiver API" https://developers.google.com/identity/sms-retriever/request
but I don`t result which I wont

This code past to MainActivity.

```
SmsRetrieverClient client = SmsRetriever.getClient(this);
                Task<Void> task = client.startSmsRetriever();
                task.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<Void>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
                    }
                });
                    task.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                       }
                    });
```

This code past to MySMSBroadcastReceiver.

```
public class MySMSBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    String message;
    Status status;
    private static MessageListener mListener;
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (SmsRetriever.SMS_RETRIEVED_ACTION.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Bundle extras = intent.getExtras();
            status = (Status) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_STATUS);
            switch(status.getStatusCode()) {
                case CommonStatusCodes.SUCCESS:
                    // Get SMS message contents
                    message = (String) extras.get(SmsRetriever.EXTRA_SMS_MESSAGE);
                    // Extract one-time code from the message and complete verification
                    // by sending the code back to your server.
                    break;
                case CommonStatusCodes.TIMEOUT:
                    // Waiting for SMS timed out (5 minutes)
                    // Handle the error ...
                    break;
            }
            mListener.MySMSBroadcastReceiver(message);
        }
    }
    public static void bindListener(MessageListener listener){
        mListener = listener;
    }
}
```

In my Manifest

```
<receiver android:name="ru.project.MBank.MySMSBroadcastReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.gms.auth.api.phone.SMS_RETRIEVED"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
```

But result get nothing.
Help what do I do wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem. First you need to generate a unique key (App Signature) that will identify message and your device. Once you generate key, your broadcaster will be able to detect message.

```
public class AppSignature extends ContextWrapper {
public static final String TAG = AppSignature.class.getSimpleName();

private static final String HASH_TYPE = "SHA-256";
public static final int NUM_HASHED_BYTES = 9;
public static final int NUM_BASE64_CHAR = 11;

public AppSignature(Context context) {
    super(context);
}

/**
 * Get all the app signatures for the current package
 * @return
 */
public ArrayList<String> getAppSignatures() {
    ArrayList<String> appCodes = new ArrayList<>();

    try {
        // Get all package signatures for the current package
        String packageName = getPackageName();
        PackageManager packageManager = getPackageManager();
        Signature[] signatures = packageManager.getPackageInfo(packageName,
                PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES).signatures;

        // For each signature create a compatible hash
        for (Signature signature : signatures) {
            String hash = hash(packageName, signature.toCharsString());
            if (hash != null) {
                appCodes.add(String.format("%s", hash));
            }
        }
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "Unable to find package to obtain hash.", e);
    }
    return appCodes;
}

private static String hash(String packageName, String signature) {
    String appInfo = packageName + " " + signature;
    try {
        MessageDigest messageDigest = MessageDigest.getInstance(HASH_TYPE);
        messageDigest.update(appInfo.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
        byte[] hashSignature = messageDigest.digest();

        // truncated into NUM_HASHED_BYTES
        hashSignature = Arrays.copyOfRange(hashSignature, 0, NUM_HASHED_BYTES);
        // encode into Base64
        String base64Hash = Base64.encodeToString(hashSignature, Base64.NO_PADDING | Base64.NO_WRAP);
        base64Hash = base64Hash.substring(0, NUM_BASE64_CHAR);
        return base64Hash;
    } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
    }
    return null;
}
```

}

After this initiate this class in your firs activity.
Hope this will help you.

Comment: Can you help me? where past this code in MainActivity? I tried but not working.

Comment: Create separate class AppSignature and paste this code is that class. After in your main activity create object of this class.

Comment: Hello Guy! Help me, I don`t resolve SMS retriever API

Comment: did you add dependency in your app? If you have not added dependency, add, implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:16.0.1"